# Parametrization of a circle, why is it $(\sin t, \cos t)$ instead of $(\sin^2t,\cos^2t)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametrization

> The equation of a circle is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.
>
> Then why is the parameterization of a circle $(r\cos(t), r\sin(t))$ and not $(r\cos^2(t), r\sin^2(t))$?

I thought what I'm supposed to do here is to eliminate $x$ and $y$ and write them in a way where I can represent them both with $t$ and then put it back into the equation? If I do that, I get

$$x = r\cos(t)$$
$$y = r\sin(t)$$

then if I put it back into the equation of the circle I get them both squared. Shouldn't the result then be $(\sin^2t,\cos^2t)$?

What's wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is not clear. Please [edit] it to tell us just what you are supposed to do, and what you have tried. Just "I put it back into my equation" is not very useful to use. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Think this way - what is the coordinate of a point on the circle?

Comment: Try drawing a diagram

Comment: The other comments are all correct, but substituting $x = r \cos^2 t, y = r \sin^2 t$ into the equation, you do *not* get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = r \cos t$, $y = r \sin t$, then $$x^2+y^2 = r^2 \cos^2 t + r^2 \sin^2 t = r^2 (\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t)$$ which is indeed $r^2$.

If $x = r \cos^2 t$, $y = r \cos^2 t$, then $$x^2 + y^2=(r \cos^2 t)^2 + (r \sin^2 t)^2 = r^2 \cos^4 t + r^2 \sin^4 t$$ This is not equal to $r^2$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

If
$(x, y) = (r\cos^2(t), r\sin^2(t))
$
then $x+y=r$
which is the equation of a straight line, not a circle.

Answer (score 0):

When we use the notation
$(x,y)$ with regards to Cartesian co-ordnates we mean that the $x$-coordinate is $x$ and the $y$-coordiante is $y$ (unsurprisingly). If we have $x$ and $y$ expressed parametrically then we can replace each variable by the equation in the given parameter it is equivalent to; eg in your case we'd replace $x$ by $r\cos{t}$.